# Who can explain exactly the meaning of put_private in Plug.Conn?

Tags: elixir

```
  @spec put_private(t, atom, term) :: t
  def put_private(%Conn{private: private} = conn, key, value) when is_atom(key) do
    %{conn | private: Map.put(private, key, value)}
  end
```

Comment: I can not understand the this snippet: %Conn{private: private} = conn

Comment: I would assume you're asking about the behavior of the function. Probably you should edit your question to remove the @spec line at the beginning because it's confusing which _put_private_ it is that you're asking about.

Answer (score 4):

[The docs](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_private/3) do a pretty good job:

> Assigns a new private key and value in the connection.
>
> This storage is meant to be used by libraries and frameworks to avoid writing to the user storage (the :assigns field). It is recommended for libraries/frameworks to prefix the keys with the library name.

Comment: %Conn{private: private} = conn is a pattern match against  the Conn which is a struct in order to get the value of private: key in the conn.

Comment: You can read about pattern matching on a map in in http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html#maps